# When creating new reactjs, project is initializing in another route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am creating new reactjs project with **npx create-react-app my-app**. When I go to terminal and start the project, I don't understand why it is generating code from another nextjs project.

[image]

When I DELETE all node modules and install them again look here it download some dependency that I didn't added to package.json
[image]

Here my **package.json** file

```js
{
  "name": "clickmedia",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Also when when enter yarn start

```js
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-scripts start
(node:3344) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3344) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
```

I don't know if I created bundle global. So how to remove them? Because my project start with this path
**http://localhost:3000/gr-en** instead of **http://localhost:3000**. I didn't created any path start with **/gr-en**

When I type **npx create-react-app my-app** and than **Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...** appear. Is it normal to start with cra-template or with react-script?

This is my network in developer tools. I use brave as a browser.When I change to localhost:3000 it automatically route me to /gr-en. But in edge, it stays in localhost:3000
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are running terminal commands from correct directory?

Comment: @Danila I dont think so. I checked my directory many times. Because when I change some text in App.js, I can see the changes

Comment: Can you also try to delete node_modules and .next folders and then reinstall and restart the app?

Comment: @Danila I added the result. I erased all nextjs projects in my computer, I deleted nodemodules related in my current project, but still pull some other depencies from anywhere else. I did not add any tailwind library.But it is adding it when yarn install. I added  it upside

Comment: *You* didn't include tailwind (as an example), but you've specified `react-scripts` 5, [which *does*](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/9673858a3715287c40aef9e800c431c7d45c05a2/packages/react-scripts/package.json#L72). This is what transitive dependencies do: include their *own* dependencies, meaning you don't need to explicitly provide and manage them yourself. The *bulk* of project dependencies will be transitive dependencies for all but the simplest projects.

Comment: @DaveNewton so why the route start with http://localhost:3000/gr-en not http://localhost:3000/. http://localhost:3000/gr-en is another route that I used in my nextjs project.  After I download react-script 5 I confront with this issue

Comment: I have no idea, but I'd explore how it handles I18N since this appears to be routing based on locale.

Comment: @DaveNewton there is a global dependecy that I couldn't solve which one. Or maybe OneDrive folder effect it .